# i am trying to install nvm using curl when i use the following command

Tags: curl

curl -6 -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
i get
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.16.2.200 port 3128: Connection timed out

Comment: Hi and welcome. I do not see a question here.

Comment: in terminal sudo apt-get install  command works fine but whenever i try to use git or curl or get i get connection timed out

Comment: It looks like you have configured your system to use an HTTP proxy

Comment: yeah there was a proxy misconfiguration and thankyou david and steeldriver :)